# Postgresql 10.x installer configures password wrong? (Windows)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am new to PostgreSQL, but I just installed 10.x and was asked to type a root/admin password which I could  not leave empty. I hence entered a password I know very well since i only intend for this to be a localhost database.

But when prompted by 3rd party application which uses PostgresSQL to login I only know password - and I can not login correctly.

Being optimistic I tried to start pgbench.exe from commandline which asks for password - but it says that password authentication failed for *my name*.

Is here anyway to reset password and setup a proper user/password account or somehow fix the situation? And maybe some kind of frontend tool I can use for testing? I have searched for pg_hba file, but I only have a "sample" file.

I have installed into path *D:\databases\Postgresql\10*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the EDB installer, when it asks for a password, that is the password for the PostgreSQL user named `postgres`, not for the user named `tom`.

Perhaps there is a way to make our 3rd party app connect as `postgres`?

Or if you want it to use the database role whose name matches your Windows account name, you should be able to connect with

```
psql.exe -U postgres postgres
```

And then:

```
create user tom with password 'hi tom';
```

Comment: Thank you - yes apparently it was for user postgres - would be greated if installer mentioned that. I assumed root or admin or similar :)